# looking to use the findstring command AGAIN

Tags: command-line

I have a file called "twister" and in that file is the word "games". I have it located in the g: drive I need to find the word "games" at the end of the sentence in the entire file (called twister). I know the parameter for end of line and search the hole drive (/s /e also /i for case sensitive (is to be ignored). Can't seem to put them all together.

Comment: Show what you've tried and what error messages you've gotten an how the result differed from what you expected. Also, did you read `help findstr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the string "games" at the end of a line (in other words, followed by a carriage return):

```
findstr /s /i /e "games" g:\twister
```

Search for the word "games" at the end of a sentence (in other words, followed by a period, question mark or exclamation point), may or may not be at the end of a line:

```
findstr /s /i "\<games[.?!]" g:\twister
```

Comment: Thankx Dennis I did use finstr/? and actually used your first command and it didn't work. So I double checked and when I was trying different prompts I actually erased the file completely (accidently). Found used command and it worked!!